# Does the C# Convert.ToDateTIme function read date as "dd/mm/yyyy" or "mm/dd/yyyy"?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, datetime

Does the C# Convert.ToDateTIme function read date as "dd/mm/yyyy" or "mm/dd/yyyy"?

I have the same application on my local machine which I uploaded to my remote shared server. It was working perfectly on my local machine reading "dd/mm/yyyy", but on my remote machine, it seems to read dates as "mm/dd/yyyy". I have the same culture setting "en-GB" on both.

I find this date conversion very unpredictable. Can anyone recommend a culture-proof way of reading date strings from a SQL Server 2005 database?

Comment: @Avinash: Given that you have more than 500 rep, I would expect that you would know how to use Markdown enough to format your questions properly. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Maybe not. The Markdown page says "(The backtick key is in the upper left corner of most keyboards.)" but Avinash's culture isn't US.

Comment: @WindowsProgrammer: I think you're very mistaken. Avinash's "culture" is almost certainly Indian (same as mine) and the US Keyboard layout is the norm in India. Plus, a user is not limited to using the keyboard to format questions because the toolbox provides links for this. I find it very strange when people defend incompetence.

Comment: Avinish told us what culture he's using. Even if Avinish came from India it looks like he/she isn't working there. But you might be right about keyboards, because I seem to remember Chinese keyboards having half their characters arranged the same as in the US. So China + India + US might make up "most" keyboards of the world.

Comment: allways use YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 4):

Well by the sounds of it... One of the settings on the server is off.

I'd go through the "Region & Language" Options with a fine tooth comb and make sure that something isn't override but if that fails.

You could try explicitly setting the Culture Info

```
         string x = "21/01/2009";

        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

        Convert.ToDateTime(x, ci);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply use the datetime data type?
Then, from your sql data reader, use: reader.GetDateTime(int column)

Another option: if you have to pass dates in strings, use the ISO format: yyyy-MM-dd

Answer (score 2):

How are your dates actually stored in SQL Server? If they're stored as `datetime` then you should be able to read them as DateTime values and not need to use Convert.ToDateTime(). Can you show us the query and/or the C# code?

**Edit**

You threw me off with the mention of SQL Server at the end of your question! Have you considered using a DateTimePicker instead of a TextBox? ASP.NET has date picker controls, right? Then it could do the parsing for you.

Comment: i want to convert the datetime from textbox.In my local server i used Convert.toDatetime("MM/dd/yyyy") and this is working .But in uploaded server its not working ....